# how to create ASP.NET MVC 4 project with different page engine?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

when I create MVC 4 project with razor view engine , I can't add view form .aspx view, anyone have an idea how to export .aspx view into project with razor view engine?

Answer (score 0):

You can choose the default view engine when you create the project.
[image]

Comment: yes I know , but I want To  mix vie engines in the same project